Database migrations in Helm charts using pre-install, pre-upgrade hook
One recommended way to perform database migrations in a Helm chart is to run a job using the pre-install and pre-upgrade hooks:
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: Job
metadata:
  name: migrate
  annotations:
    "helm.sh/hook": pre-install, pre-upgrade
    "helm.sh/hook-delete-policy": before-hook-creation, hook-succeeded
    "helm.sh/hook-weight": "3"
...

However, if the Helm charts includes deploying the database itself, how is the migration supposed to run if the  doesn’t exist yet during the pre-install phase?
A similar issue arises if we want to insert initial data (such as an initial user) using a job that runs only once before the first installation with a pre-install hook.
Is there any solution to these problems?

One tractable approach to this is to make sure your application exits if it can't find its database tables.  Now if the application container starts up but the tables it needs aren't there, it will restart.  Then you can change the initial migrations and seed data to a post-install job.
For databases in particular, I've seen a couple of different ways to handle them.  If your database is outside the cluster and a Terraform job creates them, then you don't have this dependency problem.  (The more specific model was using public-cloud-hosted databases with snapshots and backups, and a largely stateless cluster.)  I've also seen setups where there's one shared database instead of 100 databases for 100 services.  In both cases, you'll have created the database and provided Helm its configuration before you run your local chart, in which case a pre-install hook will work.

I'll also note that database migrations around upgrades are hard.  The basic problem is that a Kubernetes Deployment will create new Pods while old ones are still running, and you want this for a zero-downtime update.  But this means that, during an upgrade, you'll have both new and old code running at the same time.  No matter when you run migrations – pre-upgrade, post-upgrade, as part of container startup – some containers will be running with the "wrong" database schema.
The only approach I've used here is to have a set of human-enforced rules around migrations.  You can add tables and columns, since those won't affect old code.  If you want to delete something, you need to update the code to stop using the old table or column, but you can't include an SQL DELETE statement in a migration until you know that the deployed code isn't using the column any more.  You can't really rename columns or change their types.  You can freely change indexes.
